# What is a single word that means "poor guy" (not moneyless)?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, what single word can I use as a replacement here?
"He's been standing there and waiting all morning, poor guy."

Edit:
The synonym should be sympathetic, so no derogatory words

Comment: I think this is a bit of a "non-issue". No normal native speaker associates the cited usage with poverty.

Comment: May be that wasn't such a good example, better edit it

Comment: As an attributive adjective (before the noun), ***poor*** almost always means *in an undesirable state* (often, *to be pitied*). In principle you could switch it to ***pitiful, pitiable*** (and presumably others), but if your reason for wishing to do this is simply to avoid connotations of poverty, I suggest the entire concept is misplaced. Some possibilities (such as ***pathetic***) might skew your meaning in ways you wouldn't want if you fully understood them.

Comment: Depends a lot on whether you want an empathetic or derogatory term (likely there is nothing neutral).

Comment: (Oddly, "the poor sap" is relatively empathetic, in the right context.)

Comment: **Hapless** questioner has been downvoted.

Comment: @user13267 - I think "poor guy" in the example sentence is perfect as is, and cannot be improved upon.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking a possible single word would be

> **wretch** - [a deplorably unfortunate or unhappy person](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wretch)

Looking up its [synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/wretch) gives other candidates, but this and many on the list may have a more negative connotation that makes the person seem more immoral, rather than miserable or pathetic.  The list also made me think "loser", but that seems too harsh, poor guy.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [chump](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chump).

I think it captures the essence of "poor guy" without casting too much derision or sympathy.

Answer (score 0):

“Poor Dab” - a saying in Wales (UK) exactly describes this unfortunate person. Or “poor soul”.

Comment: "Poor soul" will be understood pretty much everywhere. "Poor dab" [wouldn't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dab_(dance)).

Comment: Can you please provide a reference?